# Unique Filter multiple sheets with ArrayFormula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have no idea how to title this post, apologize in advance.

I have several sheets with a number in Column I and a name centered and merged in columns A:H. I want to obtain the name from A:H of the corresponding value within I but do have duplicates, therefore I need the nth value when permitted. The formula I have so far works up to the point it does not autofill down as an ArrayFormula, so when I drag the formula down I get an #REF! error due to the fact that when a duplicate is found it cannot overwrite the formula below.

This will be easier to showcase: [LINK TO SHEET.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hCTEL0DiukulJUQWZTcy5D6QSS5iB7G9yAgOy09plzA/edit?usp=sharing)

Essentially, in the main sheet all the values in I:I of all the other sheets are obtained and sorted, then using that column I want to return the name that corresponds to the value, allowing for duplicates to work themselves out. I believe my issues resides in the **$B1** part at the end of the formula preventing it from being an array.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(FILTER({Sheet2!$A$1:$A;Sheet3!$A$1:$A;Sheet4!$A$1:$A},{Sheet2!$I$1:$I;Sheet3!$I$1:$I;Sheet4!$I$1:$I}=$B1)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cell F2 on the Sheet1 tab:

```
=QUERY({Sheet2!A:I;Sheet3!A:I;Sheet4!A:I},"select Col1,Col9 where Col9>0 order by Col9 asc",0)
```

You can read more about [query here.](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/google-sheets-query-sql/)

Comment: If you would kindly update the formula to reflect the final solution (containing the ">0") I will mark as solution! Just didn't know if you could edit a solution once marked.

Comment: @KevinP. Good call.  Done!